# Filter custom post type by category in REST API v2 in WordPress

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating an Android app using the WP API. I managed to show a custom post type in the REST API which can be viewed in:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/property
```

Now I want to filter properties by their category, e.g. `villa`, `home`, `rent`, etc. I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/property?filter[category_name]=villa` 
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/property?filter[category]=apartment`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was running into this issue as well with my custom post types.

You need to query by your custom taxonomy (eg. property_categories, or whatever you named it in your register_taxonomy() function) and *then* by the term.

```
&filter[taxonomy]=property_categories&filter[term]=villa
```

Answer (score 0):

This saved my own day

```
mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/property?property-status=33
```

then this was my call in my themes functions file

```
    //get custom post types in the WP-API v2
//for mobile app
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'sb_add_cpts_to_api', 10, 2 );
function sb_add_cpts_to_api( $args, $post_type ) {
if ( 'property' === $post_type ) {
$args['show_in_rest'] = true;
}
return $args;
}


//to add taxonomy for properties to API result
    add_action( 'init', 'sb_add_taxes_to_api', 30 );
    function sb_add_taxes_to_api() {
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( 'property-city', 'property-type', 'property-status' );
      foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $taxonomy->show_in_rest = true;
            $taxonomy->name;
        }
    }
```